# How to remove language translation from apt-get update?

Tags: apt

I have a NAS with a custom OpenMediaVault image that was developed by a Russian, so the translation packages were originally in Russian. However, I deleted "ru" from ***sources.list***, so that it draws from the main Debian repository. I've also changed the system locale, removing Russian from the list, and keeping only the English locale.

However, when I run ***apt-get update***, it feeds me both the English and Russian translations.

Example:

> Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
>   Hit http://ftp.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-ru

I don't know if it's actually downloading Russian translations, but because it's a NAS and I'm trying to keep OS files to a minimum, I don't want any extra and unnecessary files.

Is there a way to exclude these; and if so, how?

[Edit: I've gone to ***/etc*** to ***nano locale.gen***, and the Russian locale is properly commented out, while only the English locale is called upon. Continuing to poke around...]

Answer (score 2):

`apt-get update` will only load the package lists, to find out what's available: the actual upgrades are installed by `apt-get upgrade`.

The `Translation-ru` contains only the *package descriptions* in Russian, and is only about 420 KiB in size.

The package description translations are selected for download according to the following settings:

- the `LANG` environment variable
- the `LC_MESSAGES` environment variable (which can override the `LANG`)
- or the `APT::Acquire::Translation` setting in `/etc/apt/apt.conf` or `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*` files.

The `ru` in `sources.list` only selects where you are downloading your packages from geographically, so you might now end up downloading updates from more distant servers than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your NAS it's a WDMyCloud with Fox's OS images. For whoever stumbles on this question, the answer is

`rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*Translation-ru`

Comment: Exactly right, and this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!